# Join + Group + Aggregate in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query, which I put into a `DataGrid`:

```
var balancePerAccount = from bal in data.balanceDetails
                        join acc in data.userPaymentDetails on bal.userName equals acc.userName
                        where bal.paymentID == 0
                        group bal by bal.userName into g
                        where g.Sum(p => p.rebateBeforeService) >= 20
                        select new
                        {
                            Username = g.Key,
                            Amount = g.Sum(p => p.rebateBeforeService),
                        };
dgPaymentsPending.DataSource = balancePerAccount;
dgPaymentsPending.DataBind();
```

What I would like to do is add something inside `acc` in to the `select`. For example I would like to add `PaymentProvider = acc.PaymentProvider`. I tried flipping this every way I could think of, including getting `First()` from the group and trying to access it from there, but I can't seem to find a way to access it. I might just be missing something really simple, but I have been looking around Google for some time and I can't seem to find a comparable example. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend grouping source using anonymous type: `new { bal, acc }` and then use `First`

```
var balancePerAccount = from bal in data.balanceDetails
                        join acc in data.userPaymentDetails on bal.userName equals acc.userName
                        where bal.paymentID == 0
                        group new { bal, acc } by bal.userName into g
                        where g.Sum(p => p.bal.rebateBeforeService) >= 20
                        select new
                        {
                            Username = g.Key,
                            PaymentProvider = g.FirstOrDefault().acc.PaymentProvider,
                            Amount = g.Sum(p => p.bal.rebateBeforeService),
                        };
```